# Get drupal form structure

Tags: forms

I have created content type with CCK in which there are fields like taxonomy, filefield, textfield etc.
Now i want form structure of this content type.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 // If you can find the $form_id you can print the exact form.
 print_r($form);
}
```

Comment: just ommited drupal_render_form while returning in my custom function which is exactly same as drupal_get_form() and got the desired outcome...

Comment: @SoniKishan You asked to get the form structure, not the FROM.